# How many permutations of letters are in "MATHISFUN" without words MATH , IS , FUN

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

I'm not sure I am doing this right:

Using inclusion/exclusion principle

S = MATHISFUN has 9 letters so this have 9! permutations.

A = MATH , B = IS , C = FUN

$\#A = 6!$

$\#B = 8!$

$\#C = 7!$

$ \#(A \cap B) = 5! $

$ \#(A \cap C) = 4! $

$ \#(B \cap C) = 6! $

$ \#(A \cap B \cap C) = 3! $

So without this words we have

$ S \ (A \cup B \cup C) = 9! - (6! + 8! + 7!) - (5! + 4! +6!) + 3! $

Is it correct solution? I will be thankful for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct but it should be $9! - (6! + 8! + 7!) + (5! + 4! +6!) - 3!$ instead. If you look a t the venn diagram you will realize you need to alternate the sign for each inclusion/exclusion instead of doing it symmetrically over the four terms.

Comment: thanks I just missclicked this - instead + operation

Comment: If that's just a typo then you are correct.

Comment: @cr001 How are the intersects being calculated?

Comment: They are easy if you look at the Venn diagram ,basically you add back every 2-intersections and minus back every 3-intersections and add back every 4-intersections and so on